# Nonlinear DE with initial conditions and substitution method

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, nonlinear-system

Solve the nonlinear DE $y'' + yy' = 0$ with $y(0) = 1, y'(0) = -1$ and find an interval of definition for this solution.

My progress: After substitution $u = y' = \frac{dy}{dx}$, I found $\frac{-y^2}{2} + C = u$ where $C$ is constant. However, the sign of $C$ makes the indefinite integral unclear, unsure what to consider. Moreover, I did not understand what does "interval of definition" mean. Any help on how to continue in such circumstances and elaboration on "interval of definition" would be welcomed.

Comment: The interval of definition is the largest interval which contains $x=0$ such that your function $y$ is defined. Sometimes this might be $I = (-\infty, \infty)$, sometimes it might be shorter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugging in your initial conditions, you get that

$$-\frac{1}{2} + C = -1 \implies C = -\frac{1}{2}$$

From here just use separation of variables again

$$\int -dx = \int \frac{2\:dy}{1+y^2} \implies y = -\tan\left(\frac{x}{2}+C\right)$$

with another $+C$. Again plugging in initial conditions gives us $C= -\frac{\pi}{4}$. $y$ is only defined when $x-\frac{\pi}{2}$ is between odd multiples of $\pi$ (why?). Can you figure out which interval that would have to be for this problem?

Comment: I understood the part why $x-\frac{\pi}{2}$ should be between odd multiples of $\pi$, but which one specifically is suitable for this problem? Should it be $(-\frac{\pi}{2};\frac{\pi}{2})$? Apologize if my question is very ridiculous, I just want to be sure, especially when we have initial conditions.

Comment: @DarkKnight which $x$ value do we have to guarantee to be in the interval?

Comment: Yeah I realized that later, interval of definition for $x$ should be: $(-\frac{\pi}{2};\frac{3\pi}{2})$. Thank you for your help

Comment: @DarkKnight that's correct, and you're welcome